# Failed to run '/usr/local/go/bin/go env. The config change may not be applied correctly

Tags: linux, go, ubuntu

Whenever i try save a go file inside vc code i get this pop up `Failed to run '/usr/local/go/bin/go env. The config change may not be applied correctly.` . Also there is any no go intelliSense, code navigation, and code editing support.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you are using go modules and have go.mod file inside project directory. In this case, inside VsCode, go to preferences. Under extensions, select Go. Untick checkbox labelled "Infer GOPATH from the workspace root." for both "User" and "Workspace".
Close all terminal and VsCode instance, and restart VsCode. It should no longer display the error, and prompt message to install Go Tools. Else you can manually install go tools from VsCode (pressing crtl/cmd + shift + P), which will bring back intellisense and linting.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using **Mac OS** and **installed Go via homebrew** add

```
"go.goroot": "/opt/homebrew/opt/go/libexec"
```

To your `settings.json` file. The path may be different. Check it via `export GOROOT="$(brew --prefix golang)/libexec"`.

Also see [install go on mac](https://jimkang.medium.com/install-go-on-mac-with-homebrew-5fa421fc55f5)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. The solution is that, create a new Golang project and move all the required logic files from older project to newer project and it will work. The problem is with .mod and .sum files. It is a older project that i have created on my other laptop that has Ubuntu based [Feren](https://ferenos.weebly.com/) OS. When I moved this project to my newer laptop that has Ubuntu based [Zorin](https://zorin.com/os/) OS. It creates problem. So after trying lots of solution, I just created a new Golang project and moves all the required files and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to restart, not just reload VSCode because my Go version was updated while VSCode was running and it was looking for the older versions path.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 , Go 1.21.3, VS Code 1.83.1
setting go.alternateTools to /snap/go/current/bin/go worked for me.

Modify the value and restart VS code
`"go.alternateTools": { "go": "/snap/go/current/bin/go" }`